# On unity whenever I use time.deltatime the falling is always so slow, very new to coding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On unity whenever I use time.deltatime the falling is always so slow, very new to coding. trying to solve this problem for hours, no luck. Help appreciated!
Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class characterController : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public float forwardSpeed = 2000;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float LRspeed = 1500;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, -forwardSpeed) * Time.deltaTime;
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(-h, 0, rb.velocity.z) * LRspeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}


Changed the gravity in unity, just threw me around, added value to the y, just noclipped me through the ground plane.
```

Comment: because velocity already accounts for speed.. you wouldnt take 35mph and then to work out what speed you were doing multiply it since you last took a measurement

Answer (score -1):

Think you've just got some things the wrong way round here.

The Vector3 you're assigning to the Rigidbodies velocity is the **direction** you want the force to be applied in.

You then need to multiply this vector by the **speed** you want. But, as you know, Time.DeltaTime is required to make this consistent regardless of frame rate. So it is the speed value you must multiply with Time.DeltaTime.

You most likely don't want to be modifying the Velocity of the rigidbody directly, and [instead you should use the AddForce method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html). But if you do want to proceed with adding it directly, the same logic still applies.

This will give you the following:

```
//The vector consists of X, Y and Z. So we specify the axis to move on by setting it to 1

rb.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

I noticed you are making a CharacterController, so you probably want to apply force to the rigidbodies transform.forward property, so it will always be forward regardless of how it's rotated:

`rb.AddForce(transform.forward) * forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);`

I can see you're trying to do some other things with input, but I'm not quite sure what. If you are using a keyboard, then GetAxis will just return either 0 or 1. If you're struggling with receiving input, I would suggest keeping it simple and doing something like this to start with:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
      rb.AddForce(transform.forward) * forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I hope this clears things up!